# Why no return value is necessary with async act() call

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, formik

I don't understand how the `await` call below actually does anything since it doesn't wait for any anything inside the callback. It just returns immediately. Without it doesn't work, so I know it's necessary, but what is it actually blocking on that it wouldn't be otherwise. Doesn't it normally wait (*for queued up events and remaining state updates*) even without the `await` keyword there? How does the await with nothing asynchronous inside the callback make a difference?

I've seen many example using this pattern when I was originally searching for a solution. That's how I arrived at this.

```
import React from "react";
import {
  View,
  TextInput,
  Button
} from "react-native";
import { Formik } from "formik";
import partial from "lodash/fp/partial";

const Form = ({ task = {}, onSubmit }) => (
  <Formik initialValues={task} onSubmit={onSubmit}>
    {({ setFieldValue, handleSubmit, values }) => (
      <View>
        <TextInput
          onChangeText={partial(setFieldValue, ["task"])}
          value={values.task}
        />
        <Button onPress={handleSubmit} title="Submit" />
      </View>
    )}
  </Formik>
);

describe("...", () => {
   it("...", async () => {
       const handleSubmit = jest.fn();

       let root;

       act(() => {
           root = create(<Form onSubmit={handleSubmit} />);
       });

       // __HERE__
       await act(async () => {
           // Nothing is being returned here nor is it waiting on anything with an await call
           root.root.findByType(Button).props.onPress();
       });

       expect(handleSubmit).toHaveBeenCalled();
   })
})
```

Comment: Please be more clear on what is not working or if you are getting errors, please add to your question

Comment: _"Doesn't it normally wait even without the await keyword there?"_ Nope. The `await` is required to make it wait.

Comment: @Vencovsky The test is working as is, I just want to understand how it knows to wait asynchronously there since the code inside act isn't awaiting on anything. If inside the act callback there was at least an await call or I needed to at least return a promise there (inside the callback) it would makes sense to me. Please let me know if that makes more sense. It is monkey patching the Promise API or something so it knows where there are outstanding promises?

Comment: @AlexWayne I updated the question to hopefully make it more clear

Answer (score 1):

First thing you need to know is "What does `async` do?"

Here is an example.

```js
let a = () => 'hey'
let b = async () => 'hey'

// string
console.log(a())

// Promise object
console.log(b())
```

When adding `async` in a function, it "wrap" the function around a promise.

So you can add `async` all over your code and it will work, the only difference is that it will return a Promise object, instead of the result returned from the function.

You said

> Without it doesn't work

But you didn't explained why or what error is happening. Please be more clear on that.

But by my guesses, `act` needs to receive an promise and not an normal function. Maybe that is why you need to use `async` and without that it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry I know how await and async work very well, I think I was missing an async keyword before the test call back when I copied it. There's no error, but I got it working using random examples, I want to understand how that code actually makes a difference, since there is nothing being processed asynchronously inside the act callback itself. For instance does act also wait on all unresolved promises during the react render life cycle. If it does, does it accomplish that with monkey patching?

Answer (score 1):

*Dislcaimer: not super familar with the frameworks your using, but this is what I think is going on.*

An `async` function with no return value, does actually return a value when called without `await`. It returns a `Promise`, which provides no value when it resolves, but it when it resolves is still important. If you do use `await` then it returns `undefined` as you would expect.

I'm guessing that your code is rendering your app asynchronously here. When you run the code to press the button, I believe that whatever `Button` does is also `async`. This means your button press runs, and changes state, which schedules a re-render, which occurs in the next event loop some milliseconds later.

And I think that `act()` is hooked into the React rendering so that passing an async function to `act()` will cause it resolve only after your the next render occurs and your function you pass in also completes. Your function resolves immediately, so you now just have to wait for the render.

---

In short, this code simply says, resume execution after the next asynchronous render.

```
await act(async => { /*...*/ })
```

But this code without the `await`, execution will not actually stop and your test will continue on before the next render actually happens. The promise will will resolve after your test is done executing.

```
act(async => { /*...*/ })
```

And this code does not expect any asynchronous action at all, and will simply continue immediately, just like the previous example.

```
act({ /*...*/ })
```

Comment: I think it’s doing more than waiting for the next async rerender. From the examples I’ve seen it waits until all promises are resolved and all asynchronous renders have completed. That’s why I guess it was monkey patched the promise apo, but they was just a guess

Comment: You're probably right. But the point it waits for more than just the promise returned by the function you pass into it.